# data-ajax-success function not called in .net mvc webapplication

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC .Net web application. My _Layout page has a modal popup which render a partial view.
This Partial view _LoginPartial contains following form

```
@model WebsiteMVC.Web.ViewModels.LoginViewModel
<script>
    function LogInComplete() {
        var temp = $("#IsLoggedIn").val();
        if (temp == 'true') {
            document.location = "ThankYou";
        }
    };
</script>
<div id="myLoginForm">
    <h2>Login</h2>


    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "myLoginForm",InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "LogInComplete" }))
    {
        //Form body
    }
</div>
```

My Login method in Controller is

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    var loginSuccess = await PerformLoginActions(model);
    if (loginSuccess)
    {
        model.IsLoggedIn = true;
    }
    return PartialView("_LoginPartial", model);


}
```

Even after getting 200 response for POST request OnSuccess is not called.
I tried adding OnFailure but none of the two methods is called. 
I am new to MVC .Net

Comment: do you see any errors in console?  and Is your post action hitting while debugging?

Comment: and check if your page is reloading while debugging or not.

Comment: @JaiminDave There are no errors in console and my partial view is reloading as I can see errors returned in Modelstate. I also tried your code but LogInComplete method is not triggered.

Comment: Have you added necessary jQuery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js file ?

Comment: yes I have added jquery-3.2.1.js and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have included the unobtrusive-ajax.js script to your page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Ajax.BeginForm required unobtrusive-ajax.js to work successfully.

Comment: yes I have added jquery-3.2.1.js and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Answer (score 1):

Try using following code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

<script>
   function LogInComplete() {
    var temp = $("#IsLoggedIn").val();
    if (temp == 'true') {
        document.location = "ThankYou";
    }
};
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestAjax", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TestResult" ,OnSuccess = "LogInComplete"}))  
{
        ........
    <input type="submit" />
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult TestAjax()
{
      return PartialView("_TestAjax");
}
```